# Symfony2 ORM Entity inserting into DB

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, crud

I have this simple Entity:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="CommentTypes")
 */

class CommentTypes
{
        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
        protected $id;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100) */
        protected $name;
}
?>
```

After I Generate the CRUD and use it to Create a new record I get this error:

```
    Error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object
500 Internal Server Error - FatalErrorException
```

Error is in this piece of code - in src/AppBundle/Controller/CommentTypesController.php in this line - "return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_commenttypes_show', array('id' => $commenttypes->getId()));"

```
 * Creates a new CommentTypes entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="admin_commenttypes_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $commentType = new CommentTypes();
    $form = $this->createForm(new CommentTypesType(), $commentType);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($commentType);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_commenttypes_show', array('id' => $commenttypes->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('commenttypes/new.html.twig', array(
        'commentType' => $commentType,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us also the code you're using to create a new record?

Comment: I edited the post with code where the error exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misspelled the `$commentType` variable on line:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_commenttypes_show', array('id' => $commenttypes->getId()));
```

It should be:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_commenttypes_show', array('id' => $commentType->getId()));
```

Comment: Tried, without success. The CRUD is creating successfully the record, but it throw exception.

Comment: Yes, it's working now but like this:
`return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_commenttypes_show', array('id' => $commentType->getId()));`

Comment: It is like in my answer, no? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes same like your answer but you suggested - $commenttype, it's $commentType.

Comment: Oh, I get it, I was looking for the differences and couldn't find them. Glad I could help find the issue. ;)

Comment: The file is generated with `php console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle`, how can I make the changes persistent if I change the Entity and generate it again?

Comment: `php console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle` is only for generating the setters and getters for entity properties. So this will affect only the entity class. Let me know if I answered your question, I'm not sure if I understood it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97735/discussion-between-extreme-and-alexandru-furculita).